# How to linearize the function?

Tags: functions, linearization

I have a function

$$F(x)=\left[ a\ln\frac{y(x)}{b}-c\ln\frac{y(x)}{d} \right]^{-2},$$

where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are constant.

If the function $y(x)$ can be written as it mean value plus a disturbance, $y(x)=y_0+\epsilon * dy(x)$, where $y_0$ is a constant and $\epsilon\ll1$. How to linearize the function $F(x)$ with respect to $y_0$? In the linearization, I need to eliminate any variable preceded by $\epsilon$ with power higher than 1 and any product of two variables preceded by $\epsilon$. For example, it is easy to linearize the function $\ln\frac{y(x)}{b}$:

$$\ln\frac{y(x)}{b}=\ln(y_0+\epsilon dy)-\ln b=\ln\left[y_0(1+\epsilon \frac{dy}{y_0}) \right]-\ln b=\ln\frac{y_0}{b}+\ln\left(1+\epsilon\frac{dy}{y_0} \right)=\ln\frac{y_0}{b}+\epsilon \frac{dy}{y_0}+O(\epsilon^2).$$

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, *Welcome to the site !*

As uou take it, the problem you are facing is the composition of Taylor series and I suggest you to do it from inside to outside.

First, assuming $b>0$, $d>0$, $y(x)>0$, rewrite
$$a \log \left(\frac{y}{b}\right)-c \log \left(\frac{y}{d}\right)=(a-c)\log (y)+ [c \log(d)-a \log(b)]$$ that is to say
$$\alpha \log (y)+\beta  \quad \text{with}\quad\alpha=(a-c)\quad \text{and}\quad \beta=c \log(d)-a \log(b)$$

Now, using Taylor, just as you wrote,
$$y=y_0+y'_0 \,\epsilon\implies \log(y)=\log (y_0)+\frac{y'_0  }{y_0}\epsilon+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$
So, the quantity in brackets is

$$(\beta +\alpha  \log (y_0))+\frac{\alpha  y'_0 }{y_0}\epsilon +O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$ Square it
$$(\beta +\alpha  \log (y_0))^2+\frac{2 \alpha  y'_0   (\beta +\alpha  \log
   (y_0))}{y_0}\epsilon+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$ and now, use the long division

$$F(x)=\frac{1}{(\beta +\alpha  \log (y_0))^2}-\frac{2 \alpha  y'_0}{y_0 (\beta   +\alpha  \log (y_0))^3}\epsilon+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$

For sure, you need to replace $y_0$ by $y(x_0)$, $y'_0$ by $y'(x_0)$  and $\epsilon$ by $(x-x_0)$.

**Edit**

But, using the first principles, linearizing a function at $x_0$ is just the equation of the tangent line at this point, that is to say

$$F(x)=F(x_0)+F'(x_0)\, (x-x_0)$$
$$F(x)=\Bigg[a \log \left(\frac{y(x_0)}{b}\right)-c \log
   \left(\frac{y(x_0)}{d}\right)\Bigg]^{-2}-$$ $$2(a-c) \Bigg[a \log \left(\frac{y(x_0)}{b}\right)-c \log
   \left(\frac{y(x_0)}{d}\right)\Bigg]^{-3}\,\,\frac{y'(x_0)}{y(x_0)}\,\, (x-x_0)$$ which is much faster and does not require any $O((x-x_0)^2)$ consideration.

Comment: thank you very much, could you explain more about the last step "long division", it's not clear how to linearize the reciprocal of the expression

Comment: @user95273. For example $\frac{a+b x}{1+c x}=a+(b-ac) x+\cdots$